# Magento 2.4.4, Product count in layered navigation is incorrect after setting "Display Out of Stock Products" to "Yes"

Tags: magento2, indexing

Magento 2.4.4, Product count in layered navigation is incorrect after setting "Display Out of Stock Products" to "Yes". (**STORES->Configuration->CATALOG->Inventory->Display Out of Stock Products**)

Any idea why this happening?

Should show the correct product count in layered navigation after setting "Display Out of Stock Products" to "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

Have you done proper indexing? because the layered navigation has many issues created due to indexing so please first do index:reindex and cache:fluse CMD.

After doing this still did not work so checked your layered navigation product count function there may be some missed conditions applied to the file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check for Errors in var/log.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

*Run cron *

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

In composer in **config** section **cweagans/composer-patches** was set to **false** for some reason when set to **true** patch was applied successfully